# Key Usage for CA/Subordinate CA

Tags: ssl-certificate

I had a private key/certificate used for the last 10 years. However, now Apache refuses to start with this private key (it's only 1024bit long) and I want to create a new CA for my lab and explore the subordinate CA as well.

Now, I want to create a new CSR for both the CA and the subordinate CA. I am using Ansible for the creation of the keys/csr/certs, by the way.

Now my questions: I understand that you can limit he usage of a certificate/public key by using the relevant option (key usage and extended_key_usage).

My question is:

1. Do I need to specify any restriction for the CA/subCA?
2. If so, which restrictions should I apply?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to specify any restriction for the CA/subCA? If so, which restrictions should I apply?

If it's your lab, you actually don't need/ don't must to specify any KU or EKU (key usage or extended key usage). However - in my opinion it's better if you do it (to be as close to the real env as possible and some frameworks may complain about it)

You may actually check how common CAs are building their certificate chain. What I use:

CA certificate:

```
KU: Digital Signature, Certificate Signing, Off-line CRL Signing, CRL Signing
Basic constraint: Subject Type=CA, Path Length Constraint=0
```

Server / client certificate:

```
KU :  Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
EKU:  Server Authentication, Client Authentication
Basic constraint: Subject Type=End Entity
```

Though it depends what do you want to do with the certificates. There are several nice docs around, such as [this one](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Certificate_System/8.0/html/Admin_Guide/Standard_X.509_v3_Certificate_Extensions.html)

Comment: Many thanks!
Yes, my target to emulate the real environment, not to just install a certificate! This is easy and quite common nowdays. But, obviously I need it for tests/learning purposes.

Comment: Do I use the same KU/EKU/BC for the subCA as well? 

Also, I think that I need to set the `Path Length Constraint` to 1 if I want to use a subCA, correct?